# нужно получить ID всех пользователей в беседе через токен группы

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, методы

мне нужно получить ID всех участников беседы в вк
я пробовал получить с помощью методов "messages.getChat" и "messages.getChatUsers
мне выдаёт вот такую ошибку:
[27] Group authorization failed: method is unavailable with group auth.
пожалуйста помогите с кодом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эта ошибка возникает, так как вы пытаетесь использовать API методы, которые могут быть вызваны только с ключом доступа пользователя (не сообщества). Написано в документации [здесь](https://dev.vk.com/method/messages.getChat) и [здесь](https://dev.vk.com/method/messages.getChatUsers). Есть 2 решения:

1. Создать Standalone приложение и получить ключ через него (Нужны права доступа messages, а такие права могут получить только приложения, прошедшие модерацию);
2. Использовать метод messages.getConversationMembers ([Документация](https://dev.vk.com/method/messages.getConversationMembers)).